# 'Relaunching tuncfg' keeps showing up in my console

Tags: macos, terminal, console

I was scanning my Mac OS X with sophos antivirus and opened the console. I see this over and over again.

How do I tell whatever it is to stop trying to launch tuncfg? I recently reinstalled my operating system because I accidentally messed up some key library for using the terminal when trying to install macruby.

```
3/13/11 11:27:32 PM com.hamachix.tuncfgd[856]   /usr/sbin/tuncfgrelaunch: line 8: tuncfg:: command not found
3/13/11 11:28:32 PM com.hamachix.tuncfgd[865]   Relaunching tuncfg
3/13/11 11:28:32 PM com.hamachix.tuncfgd[865]   /usr/sbin/tuncfgrelaunch: line 8: tuncfg:: command not found
3/13/11 11:29:32 PM com.hamachix.tuncfgd[875]   Relaunching tuncfg
3/13/11 11:29:32 PM com.hamachix.tuncfgd[875]   /usr/sbin/tuncfgrelaunch: line 8: tuncfg:: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hamachix.*.plist` and `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.hamachix.*.plist`; any matching files should be disabled in `launchd` and then removed.

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hamachix.tuncfgd.plist
$ sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.hamachix.tuncfgd.plist
```

(The above example is a guess based on the logged `launchd` job name and pid; the actual file name(s) and location(s) may be different.)

Comment: thanks, those commands worked. I don't see those messages in console anymore.